# Last activity might refer to author of deleted answer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, last-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Incorrect last activity user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75828/incorrect-last-activity-user)

Here's a question I made (I'm a dumbo I know)

[SQL server date error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508532/sql-server-date-error)

Anyway, some questions show user "Xxx" as the last activity on the question, when there is nothing in the question from them, I assume this is because they write an answer and delete it.

Can be a little confusing sometimes, maybe when a deletion is made it can re-calibrate the satellites etc so that it shows the actual last activity?

Comment: It's still useful for users with >10k reputation, as they can see those deleted posts. (True, in theory caching for <10k and >10k could be different, but maybe that's still hard to implement?)